# I need to make a proxy enpoint for "Application Insights for web pages" telemetry calls (Azure Function Proxy fails CORS Options call)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights, custom-url

I have an html app with [Application Insights for web pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript) and Azure Function api. Application Insights is sending telemtry via calls to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track . I'd like this trafic to go through one of the following urls:

- a url on my API (i.e. my-app.azurewebsites.net/telemetry)
- a url on additional API I'd make (i.e. my-app-telemetry.azurewebsites.net/telemetry)
- some way to add a custom url endpoint to my Application Insights on Azure?

Essentially, I need to make a proxy endpoint in my API. I tried [Azure Function Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies), but no luck so far, I'm getting HTTP code 400 - Bad request.

Update, the Azure Function Proxy I tried looks like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Application insights": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "telemetry",
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST",
                    "OPTIONS"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

@naile provided a solution. Azure Function Proxies by default do not proxy CORS calls. You should navigate to "Platform Features" => "CORS" and remove everything you see there (see screenshot in accepted answer).

By default it contains

```
"https://functions.azure.com",  
"https://functions-staging.azure.com",  
"https://functions-next.azure.com"
```

Remove those and Azure Function Proxy should now forward CORS calls also.

In you Azure Function template, it should look like this

```
"cors": {
    "allowedOrigins": [], //this should be empty array
    "supportCredentials": false
}
```

Comment: May I ask for what purpose? Then I can probably  give a better answer

Comment: @Peter Bons I'm in a situation where I can use Application Insights, but I should avoid calls to 3-rd party urls from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly this problem recently. Turns out OPTIONS requests are *not* proxied with the default azure function CORS setup. The 400 you are seeing comes from the azure function not allowing your origin.

Simple fix: remove all entries under CORS settings and you're allowed to proxy OPTIONS requests.

[image]